# Does a MS Visual Studio 2010/.NET platform project work seamlessly with Mono/MonoDevelop?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mono, monodevelop

Does a MS Visual Studio 2010/.NET platform project work seamlessly with Mono/MonoDevelop?

Specially, projects are check-in to the SVN server using MS Visual Studio 2010 in Windows, and I need to use work in the same SVN hosted project using MonoDevelop in Linux, will there be any issues?

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Mono 2.2.1 and Visual Studio 2010 simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132144/using-mono-2-2-1-and-visual-studio-2010-simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the FAQ:

http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#Can_I_import_my_Visual_Studio_2K5.2b_project_into_MonoDevelop.3f

> **Can I import my Visual Studio 2K5+ project into MonoDevelop?**
>
> MonoDevelop can open, manipulate and save MSBuild-based projects directly in mopst cases. In fact, since MonoDevelop 2.0 the default project format has been VS2008-style MSBuild projects, but VS2005 and VS1010 formats are also handled.

Comment: You may pay attention to the fact that Visual Studio and MonoDevelop are maintained by different teams, so their ways to change MSBuild scripts (inside the project files) are different. Personally I prefer to use Visual Studio to modify the project files (csproj/vbproj) and check in such changes from VS. On Mono side, I avoid project changes, and only check in file changes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132144/using-mono-2-2-1-and-visual-studio-2010-simultaneously