# Where to get MonoTools for Visual Studio 2010/2012 plug-in. No luck with their web site as it is down

Tags: mono

I have been trying to get the MonoTools for Visual Studio from their web site (mono-tools.com). But with no luck. Where to get MonoTools for Visual Studio 2010/2012 plug-in?

Aditya.

Answer (score 20):

You can easily modify the MonoTools installer to work with VS2012. `.vsix` files are ZIP files. In the root of the zip, you'll see a file named `extension.vsixmanifest`, which lists the versions of Visual Studio that are supported by the extension.

Basically,

1. Download the MonoTools package
2. Rename it to have a `.zip` extension
3. Right-click and select "open" - you don't want to extract the file, just open the archive using the built-in Windows mechanism
4. Copy `extension.vsixmanifest` anywhere - say, to your desktop.
5. Open it up in a text editor (I love Notepad++, EMACS is also pretty awesome under OSX.)
6. Change the `SupportedProducts` key to the following:

> ```
> <SupportedProducts>
>   <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
>     <Edition>VSTS</Edition>
>     <Edition>VSTD</Edition>
>     <Edition>Pro</Edition>
>   </VisualStudio>
>   <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
>     <Edition>VSTS</Edition>
>     <Edition>VSTD</Edition>
>     <Edition>Pro</Edition>
>   </VisualStudio>
> </SupportedProducts>
> ```

1. Copy the modified file back into the archive.
2. Rename it from `.zip` to `.vsix`
3. Run it. The Visual Studio Version Selector should appear and let you pick VS2012.

If the `Mono` menu item doesn't appear after restarting VS, you may need to run

`devenv /setup`

from a VS command prompt (or, from c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11\common7\ide).

This works for just about any VS2010 extension.

Comment: And where to get Mono Tools ? http://mono-tools.com/ just redirects to http://xamarin.com/

Comment: @Fulproof I can't really host someone else's download. When this answer was posted in January 2013, the download for VS2010 was still available from Xamarin. I have no doubt it's still out there somewhere. Their new tools ( including VS plugin) are pretty good and worth an eval.

Answer (score 2):

That was a former product from Novell, and it is no longer offered or developed.

Xamarin doesn't offer it either.

Answer (score 0):

can get it from here: http://mono-tools.com/

free if you do their survey

but i don't see a vs2012 version

Answer (score -7):

It costs at minimum $999.00 - https://store.xamarin.com/ and is included as part of Mono for Android.  Here's a screenshot of what it looks like after it's installed.

There is also a training course on this from PluralSight -- http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents/android-intro

[image: Visual Studio add-in for Mono for Android]

Comment: That's Mono for Android. MonoTools is a different product.